# Rails 4 - scopes - form of expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, scopes

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have models for user, profile and project.

The associations are:

```
User has_one :profile
Profile belongs_to :user & has_many :projects
Projects belongs_to :profile.
```

In my profile show page, I am trying to show the projects that belong to the profile.

I have tried to write a scope in my project model as:

```
scope :by_profile, lambda { | profile_id | where(:profile_id => profile_id) }
```

Then, in my profile show page, I have tried to use that scope as:

```
<% Project.by_profile.sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
                        <div class="row">
                            <% group.compact.each do |project| %>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="indexdisplay">
                                    <%= image_tag project.hero_image_url, width: '80px', height: '80px' if project.hero_image.present? %>
                                    <br><span class="indexheading"> <%= link_to project.title, project %> </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <% end %>
                    <% end %>        
                        </div>
```

I'm new to scopes and still trying to get a grip on how things work. I'm slightly surprised that if i replace 'by_profile' with 'all' it does actually show an array of projects (I think every project, rather than just those created by the profile id for the relevant profile page).

Does anyone know how to write scopes? Is there something I'm supposed to do in the profiles controller to help make this work?

Comment: why don't use use `Project.where(profile_id: 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do here

```
Project.by_profile..
```

is not working because you have defined the scope `by_profile` with arity of one (it should get the `proffile_id`), but you do not pass any.

```
Project.by_profile(params[:profile_id]).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3) # will work
```

But easier here would be just to use the associations:

```
Profile.find(params[:id]).projects.sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)..
```

What you should know about scopes? They are pretty much "`class`" methods, but written in a nicer way :)

When you call a scope make sure that you pass right amount of arguments to it.

Here is a shorter way to define your scope (`->` is called stubby lambda):

```
scope :by_profile, ->(profile_id) { where(profile_id: profile_id) }
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, when I try that, I get an error that says: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: @user2860931 what exactly do you try?

Comment: the scope the way you wrote it at the end of your post:  scope :by_profile, ->(profile_id) { where(profile_id: profile_id) }

Comment: and how do you use it? Do you pass the `profile_id` to `Project.by_profile(PROFILE_ID_HERE)`?

Comment: I tried it the same way as I had it originally, and I also tried: <% Project.all.by_profile.sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>

Comment: @user2860931 as I explained, you HAVE TO PASS the `profile_id` to the scope. Otherwise how do you expect it to narrow the result? `Project.by_profile(1).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)`

Comment: but how do you do that?

Comment: @user2860931 you just pass the id :) `Project.by_profile(1).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)`

Comment: so do you mean: Project.by_profile(@profile_id).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)

Comment: @user2860931 this is exactly what I mean, but inplace of `@profile_id` there should an object that points to integer. EXAMPLE:  `@profile_id = Profile.first.id`. `Project.by_profile(@profile_id).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)`

Comment: That's what I thought I was achieving by writing a scope. I don't know how to express the id, so that it points to the profile id of the profile page on which the projects are displayed. I'm lost for how to figure this out.

Comment: If I try: Project.by_profile(profile_id).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>, I get this error: undefined local variable or method `profile_id' for #<#<Class:0x007f868f7e5050>:0x007f8691e20828>

Comment: @user2860931, that is pretty simple, have a look: `Project.by_profile(params[:profile_id]).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)`.  (or `params[:id]` depending on url) I did not know that was the problem.

Comment: @user2860931 did you try it out?

Comment: The scope doesnt work (it gives all the projects by all the profiles). But it does work if I do: Profile.find(params[:id]).projects.sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(3)..

Comment: The scope in this case makes no sense, because it is achievable by existing associations, and scope brings to ease. But in general scopes are very powerful things